# Unable to access arrays in JavaScript objects in React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to access comments array in my DishDetail Component but the compiler is throwing me Uncaught error: comments is not defined.

```js
export const DISHES =
    [
        {
        id: 0,
        name:'Uthappizza',
        image: 'assets/images/uthappizza.png',
        category: 'mains',
        label:'Hot',
        price:'4.99',
        description:'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
        comments: [
            {
            id: 0,
            rating: 5,
            comment: "Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
            author: "John Lemon",
            date: "2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
            },
            {
            id: 1,
            rating: 4,
            comment: "Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
            author: "Paul McVites",
            date: "2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
            },
```

Here is the code snippet for DishDetail Component. When I am running RenderComments component with props.dish.comments, the browser is throwing me an uncaught error: comments is not defined. I have consoled log and props.dish is grabbing me the information of a particular dish but by typing .comments is no accessing me to comments array.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Card, CardImg, CardBody, CardText, CardTitle } from 'reactstrap';



    function RenderComments({comments}) {
        if (comments == null) {
            return (<div></div>)
        }
        const cmnts = comments.map(comment => {
            return (
                <li key={comment.id}>
                    <p>{comment.comment}</p>
                    <p>-- {comment.author},
                    &nbsp;
                    {new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', {
                            year: 'numeric',
                            month: 'long',
                            day: '2-digit'
                        }).format(new Date(comment.date))}
                    </p>
                </li>
            )
        })
        return (
            <div className=''>
                <h4> Comments </h4>
                <ul className='list-unstyled'>
                    {cmnts}
                </ul>

            </div>
        )
    }

    function RenderDish({dish}) {
        if (dish != null)
            return(
               <div>
                    <Card key={dish.id}>
                        <CardImg width="100%" src={dish.image} alt={dish.name} />
                        <CardBody>
                        <CardTitle>{dish.name}</CardTitle>
                        <CardText>{dish.description}</CardText>
                        </CardBody>
                    </Card>
               </div>

            );
        else
            return(
                <div></div>
            );
    }   

    const DishDetail = (props) =>  {

        return (
            <div className="container">
                <div className='row'>
                    <div className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
                        <RenderDish dish={props.dish}/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
                        <RenderComments comments={props.dish && props.dish.comments}/>
                        {console.log(props.dish.comments)}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }


export default DishDetail
```

Comment: *Where* does it say that?

Comment: When I am running RenderComments component inside my DishDetail component.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing an empty array. Just pass `<RenderComments comments={props.dish}/>` . And in your function `RenderComments` use `const cmnts = comments.comments.map(comment => {`